# how to define two fields as unique in yii model rules

Tags: php, yii

I have a table which combination of its two fields should be unique. I guess something like

```
array('field1 field2', 'unique'),
```

in rules() method may works but it seems not! What can I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
array('field1', 'UniqueAttributesValidator', 'with'=>'field2'),
```

For more information, please visit http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/unique-attributes-validator/